# Ubuntu 12.04 UEFI dualboot Win7

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7, uefi

I have new laptop Asus N76 with 500GB HDD and 256 SSD. Windows 7 is installed on HDD with  partitions:

```
/dev/sda1  fat32    200MB boot (GPT)
/dev/sda2  unknown  128MB msftres
/dev/sda3  ntfs     94GB (Win 7)
/dev/sda4  ntfs     20GB  hidden,diag
```

I want to install 12.04 on SSD disk. Is it possible to install GRUB2 at `/dev/sda1` partition? Is Ubuntu installer ready for that? Is there some configuration for GRUB2 to setup boot path for Windows 7 (HDD) and Ubuntu 12.04 (SSD)?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info)

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  The Ubuntu installer should take care of that for you, but if you already have an installation or something, you can install the grub-efi packages.  Running `grub-install /dev/sdX` will install grub as the default boot entry and copy the needed files to /boot and your first partition.  You can then chainload to windows (assuming the installer doesn't detect this option automatically).

I have an EFI boot of Ubuntu working on my MacbookPro (which I am using to post this).  You can build your own grub image (detailed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting)) for maximum portability (which I recommend).  If you build your own image, it will work as a recovery image even when you don't have Ubuntu installed.

To summarize:

- The Ubuntu installer will setup grub for you.
- The installer should detect Windows for you.
- If it does not, use your intellect to find a way to boot into your installation and install `grub2-efi-amd64` or similar package and run `grub-install /dev/sda1`.  Note that this will squash your current boot option and make grub the default.  You may also want to run `grub-update`.